How to generate a class with macros in C++?
I want to write some macros, using like this:
MY_ENUM_BEGIN(fun)
    ENUM_ENTRY(item1, 1, "item 1")
    ENUM_ENTRY(item2, 2, "item 2")
MY_ENUM_END()

which expands to the following C++ code:
struct fun
{
    const static my_item<fun> item1(1, "item 1"); // "fun" is the parameter of the macro "MY_ENUM_BEGIN"
    const static my_item<fun> item2(2, "item 2");

    std::map<int, my_item<fun>> m_map;
    static void register_item()
    {
        m_map[1] = item1;
        m_map[2] = item2;
    }
};

How to do this?
I tried to define a macro inside another macro definition:
#define MY_ENUM_BEGIN(name) \
    struct name \
    {\
    #define ENUM_ENTRY(entry_name, index, text) \
        const static my_item<name> entry_name(index, text); \
        // ...

but that did not work (the second define was considered as an parameter, which does not exists).

Remove \  in {\ . You can't define the ENUM_ENTRY macro only between MY_ENUM_BEGIN(fun) and MY_ENUM_END. Macros don't have scopes, nor do they "remember" context. You need to define it unconditionally. You also need to add name/fun to each ENUM_ENTRY macro argument as well.

Just use magic enum.

In some cases, using a code generator is the way to go. In this case though, you could get away with a simple typedef fun base_type; from the first macro, you could then use base_type in the other macros in the middle.

BTW: Macros are evil! In general, think twice about using them. If in doubt, consider heading over to codereview.stackexchange.com and ask others to look over your code there, make sure to first read their site guidelines though!

Try to generate a class with macros by creating an enum-like struct, initializing the items and map.
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct my_item {
    int value = 0;
    std::string name;

    constexpr my_item(int v, const char* n) : value(v), name(n) {}
    constexpr my_item() = default;
};

#define MY_ENUM_BEGIN(name)                              \
    struct name {                                        \
        using enum_type = name;                          \
        static std::map<int, my_item<enum_type>> m_map;  \
        static void register_items();                    \

#define ENUM_ENTRY(entry_name, index, text)              \
        const static my_item<enum_type> entry_name;      

#define MY_ENUM_END()                                    \
    };

#define DEFINE_ENUM_ITEM(enum_name, item_name, index, text) \
    const my_item<enum_name::enum_type> enum_name::item_name(index, text);

#define DEFINE_ENUM_MAP(enum_name)                            \
    std::map<int, my_item<enum_name::enum_type>> enum_name::m_map; \
    void enum_name::register_items() {                        \
        m_map[item1.value] = item1;                           \
        m_map[item2.value] = item2;                           \
    }

MY_ENUM_BEGIN(fun)
    ENUM_ENTRY(item1, 1, "item 1")
    ENUM_ENTRY(item2, 2, "item 2")
MY_ENUM_END()

DEFINE_ENUM_ITEM(fun, item1, 1, "item 1")
DEFINE_ENUM_ITEM(fun, item2, 2, "item 2")

DEFINE_ENUM_MAP(fun)

int main() {
    fun::register_items();

    for (const auto& [key, item] : fun::m_map) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << key << ", Name: " << item.name << ", Value: " << item.value << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

